# HTML: Preventing marquee area from being empty?

Tags: html, marquee

There's a marquee that goes up.
When the text is done scrolling (before it comes up again), the marquee area becomes empty for about 2 seconds and then then comes back up again.

Is there any way to prevent it from being empty, and making the first line come up before the last one goes up?

http://jsfiddle.net/WArVQ/2/

Comment: I assume you're using a JavaScript plugin of some sort. Do you know which one?

Comment: We have little to go on. Please include the implementation code/markup/style relevant to your approach, and preferably also a http://jsfiddle.net demo.

Comment: no no javascript plugin. It's pure html's <marquee>

Comment: there you go. http://jsfiddle.net/WArVQ/2/

Comment: No, that's what we have out of the box. If you want anything more than that you will have to use JavaScript to build your own marquee.

Comment: i see. thought there was some attribute i could apply on the element for that. do you know any javascript/jquery plugin that could help me?

Comment: marquee tag is deprecated by W3C. Strongly adviced to find another solution for your needs. e.g. css marquee

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Scroll demo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: grey">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var maxy = 200; // adjust
        var lineHeight = 17; // adjust
        var lines = new Array("line1", "line2", "line3");
        var textDivs = new Array(lines.length);
        for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
            var divx = document.createElement("div");
            var divxText = document.createTextNode(lines[i]);
            divx.style.top=String(maxy-(lines.length-i)*lineHeight)+"px";
            divx.style.position="absolute";
            divx.appendChild(divxText);
            textDivs[i] = divx;
            document.getElementById("container").appendChild(divx);
        }

        window.setInterval("scroll()", 50);
        function scroll() {
            for(var i=0;i<textDivs.length;i++) {
                var divx = textDivs[i];
                var y = parseInt(divx.style.top);
                y = y-1;
                if(y<0) y = maxy-lineHeight;
                divx.style.top =String(y)+"px";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```